# AG Grid - restore default sort if no other column is sorted

Tags: javascript, sorting, vue.js, ag-grid

My ag-grid has a default sort `this.options.defaultSortColumn`, by which the data is sorted once initialized. Now when the user sorts by another column and then removes the sort again (by clicking on the header 3 times), I'd like to restore the default sort and sort the data by the default column again. I tried the following:

```
postSort () {
  if (this.gridApi) {
    let currentSort = this.gridApi.getSortModel()
    console.log(currentSort)
    if (this.options.defaultSortColumn && currentSort && currentSort.length === 0) {
      // reset default sort, if no other sort is active
      this.gridApi.setSortModel({
        colId: this.options.defaultSortColumn,
        sort: (this.options.defaultSortDir || 'asc').toLowerCase()
      })
    }
  }
}
```

But this causes a `Maximum call stack size exceeded`, I assume because it sets the sort and then runs the `postSort` event again, before the `getSortModel()` is updated, so it just keeps calling the event over and over. Am I doing something wrong? Or are there other ways to restore a default sort when no other column is sorted by?

Comment: where are you using this postSort method? on every column??

Comment: @NagaSaiA no, I have it in the gridOptions on the grid itself, so `<ag-grid-vue :postSort="postSort">`

Comment: on option is to set default sort model on load to  a variable (say defaultSort) and use onSortChanged grid API event and check the currentSort.length and set default sort using this.gridApi.setSortModel(defaultSort) instead of using postSort

Comment: onSortChanged: (e) => {
        console.log(e.api.getSortModel())
    }

Comment: @NagaSaiA thanks, you helped me find the solution. My problem was, that I called `setSortModel( {...} )` but you have to call `setSortModel( [ {...} ] )`, a bit confusing, but it works now. Thanks again!

Comment: posted comments as answer with steps and issue is with the postSort which is getting called multiple times for each row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To sum up because there is some confusion going on. The `setSortModel` function should have an array as argument not an object.

The correct way (React example)

```
  <AgGridReact onSortChanged={e => {
     if (!e.api.getSortModel().length) {
       e.api.setSortModel([
         {
          colId: 'columnId',
          sort: 'desc' // 'asc'
         }  
       ])
     }   
   }
```

Answer (score 5):

You could also reset the `gridOptions` state to what it was while initializing the grid.

```
this.gridColumnApi.resetColumnState();
```

From the docs -

> resetColumnState() - Sets the state back to match the originally
>   provided column definitions.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below ag grid event - onSortChanged and check for the length of current sort

1. Assign default sort to variable (say defaultSort) on load
2. Using onSortChanged grid API event, check the currentsort length

   `onSortChanged: (e) => { console.log(e.api.getSortModel()) }`
3. If length is 0, setdefault sort using  this.gridApi.setSortModel(defaultSort)